# get application url from current request

Tags: c#, request, httprequest, httpcontext

I am writing a c# application.

I am accessing a page eg http://dev.mysite.com/page.aspx

How can I retrieve from the current context this http://dev.mysite.com/

I want to use this when creating url's in different environments so need to read it from the current request context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://dev.mysite.com/page.aspx");
string authority = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
// authority will equal to http://dev.mysite.com
```

or if you are inside this `page.aspx` you could directly use the `Request.Url` property:

```
string authority = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```